# Rmarkdown - pdf output - stop iterations from printing

Tags: r, pdf, printing, iteration, r-markdown

I am trying to produce Rmarkdown pdf output.

Function RankAggreg() (from package RankAggreg) runs multiple iteration during the analysis that are also printed in my pdf output.

Does somebody have idea how can I stop iteration from printing in my pdf output?
I have tried using all possible variation of results = "hide", echo, include but nothing helped.

```
---
title: "<center> Example <center>"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: true
    latex_engine: xelatex
  fontsize: 10pt
  
header-includes:
- \pagenumbering{gobble}
---
```

```
library(rmarkdown)
library(tinytex)
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=TRUE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, cache = TRUE)
```

```
library(RankAggreg)

data(geneLists)

RA_results_seedlings <- RankAggreg(
  geneLists, 10, method = c("CE"), distance = c("Spearman"), 
  seed = 100, rho = 0.1, standardizeWeights = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `verbose = FALSE` in the `RankAggreg()` function

```
RA_results_seedlings <- RankAggreg(
geneLists, 10, method = c("CE"), distance = c("Spearman"), 
seed = 100, rho = 0.1, standardizeWeights = TRUE,
verbose = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set `results = "hide"` directly in the particular chunk, the text output is hidden and only plots are displayed in the PDF:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, results = "hide"}
library(RankAggreg)

data(geneLists)

RA_results_seedlings <- RankAggreg(
  geneLists, 10, method = c("CE"), distance = c("Spearman"), 
  seed = 100, rho = 0.1, standardizeWeights = TRUE)
```
````

[image: knitr]

(Using `knitr::opts_chunk$set()` for this does not work for me either.)